# use the SObject Tree resource to create attachments and notes for opportunity VIA POST Ajax

Tags: post

How do I add notes and attachments to opportunity objects via SObject Tree. I am dong this via java script ajax POST
"New Notes"
"Attach File"

```
"Opportunities": {
 "records": [{
   "attributes": { "type": "Opportunity", "referenceId": "opp1" },
   "name": "Closing Soon",
   "closedate": "2018-09-01",
   "stagename": "Prospecting"
 }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Note or Attachment simply by providing them as children records of the parent record; reference the relationship name `Notes` or `Attachments` to insert the appropriate type of record.

Example:

```
{
 "records": [{
   "attributes": { "type": "Opportunity", "referenceId": "opp1" },
   "name": "Closing Soon",
   "closedate": "2018-09-01",
   "stagename": "Prospecting",
     "Notes": { "records": [{
       "attributes": { "type": "Note", "referenceId": "note1" },
       "title": "This is a note",
       "body": "This is the content of the note"
     }]},
     "Attachments": { "records": [{
       "attributes": { "type": "Attachment", "referenceId": "att1" },
       "name": "filename.txt",
       "body": "VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgY29udGVudCBvZiB0aGUgYXR0YWNobWVudA==",
       "contenttype": "text/plain"
     }]}
 }]
}
```

Please note that the body of an attachment must be base64-encoded.

Comment: so if the user browse a file from their computer image, or pdf, it has to change to base64 first , and then pass that to the body

Comment: @Metawaa Yes. You can use FileReader.readAsDataURL to convert the file to base64, then upload the body part.

Comment: do I need to have the extension for the file in conteentType? like if is PDF or JPEG?

Comment: @Metawaa Use the content type that the browser gives you from the data URI. It should be a mime type, like "image/jpeg" or "application/pdf".

Comment: how do you make it so if attachment is empty, still submits the sobject tree. right now when its empty , it errors out

Comment: @Metawaa Don't send an empty Attachments list. This means you'll need to add a bit of logic to your code.

Comment: Yah not every time there will be an attachment. its fine, I guess I can make it so create an object only when its not empty